# Calcular percentagem entre duas datas MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, query

Bom dia!

Eu queria calcular a percentagem de quantas vezes uma classificação aparece entre duas datas, as classificações são distribuídas em "vermelho", "amarelo" e "verde".

Esta é a tabela "questionario":

[image: Tabela Questionario]

Eu tentei da seguinte forma:

```
$percentagem_verm=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT COUNT(q.pergunta_id) / t.total * 100 as perc, classificacao FROM questionario q,
( SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM questionario) t
WHERE q.classificacao = 'vermelho' AND data BETWEEN '".$_POST["datainicial"]."' AND '".$_POST["datafinal"]."'
 GROUP BY q.classificacao "));
```

As datas eu pego pelo URL e funciona certo, porém a percentagem que retorna está errada, ela só é correta quando eu escolho todos as informações da base de dados, mas se for uma data específica fica tudo mal...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente algo mais ou menos assim

```
select ((count(if((classificacao = 'vermelho'), 1, 0)) / count(classificacao)) * 100) as perc
      ,classificacao
  from questionario
 where data BETWEEN '".$_POST["datainicial"]."' AND '".$_POST["datafinal"]."'
 group by classificacao
```

Caso não de certo o de cima tente sem o group by

```
select ((count(if((classificacao = 'vermelho'), 1, 0)) / count(classificacao)) * 100) as perc
  from questionario
 where data BETWEEN '".$_POST["datainicial"]."' AND '".$_POST["datafinal"]."'
```

**EDITADO**

Desculpe, trabalho mais com firebird :D

No mysql faça assim

```
select ((count(CASE WHEN classificacao like 'vermelho' THEN 1 END) / count(classificacao)) * 100) as perc
  from questionario
 where data BETWEEN '".$_POST["datainicial"]."' AND '".$_POST["datafinal"]."
```

Obs.: Só confira se coloquei os nomes corretos

Comment: Eu tentei com a sua query, infelizmente ainda não deu, ele retorna sempre 100% ...

Comment: Confira a edição da minha resposta

Comment: Funcionou certinho, muito obrigada!! Peço desculpa nao ter marcado a sua  resposta como correta, eu tinha confirmado a outra primeiramente, mas a sua deu perfeitamente!

Comment: Sem problemas, no caso você marcou a minha como correta também e depois removeu hahaha Mas vai de você o que for melhor para o seu problema, ajudando é o que importa.

Comment: Sim desculpe mesmo, ainda pensei q desse para marcar as duas, mas obrigada!

Answer (score 3):

O percentual será determinado pela quantidade de itens de determinada classificação dividido pelo total de itens de todas as classificações, mas os demais filtros - no seu caso aparentemente são somente datas - precisam ser os mesmos na fonte do total e dos itens por classificação.

Ou seja: **`TotalClassificacaoPeriodo / TotalPeriodo`**.

O `SELECT` ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
SELECT q.classificacao, (COUNT(*) / t.Total) * 100 AS Percentual
FROM Questionario q,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total 
   FROM Questionario aux 
   WHERE aux.data >= '20180201' AND
         aux.data <= '20180228') t
WHERE q.data >= '20180201' AND
    q.data <= '20180228'
GROUP BY q.classificacao
```

<sup>* Eu usei o subselect no join, porque o **`Total`** será único aplicado para todos os regitros.

** A data no filtro está no formato `YYYYMMDD`</sup>

Note que o filtro é o mesmo nas duas consultas.

[**Você pode conferir nesse cenário que criei no SQL Fiddle para demonstrar essa lógica funcionando**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/413353/12)

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Perfeito!! Funcionou certinho, acrescentei só a condição `where q.classificacao='vermelho'`!! Muito obrigada

Comment: Ah, @Ana Okay. Eu não prestei atenção nesse detalhe. No caso desse filtro ele deve ficar somente no select externo. Vou editar na resposta

Comment: Sim, eu pus de fora

Answer (score 0):

Você está calculando o total 'SELECT count(*) as total from questionario' sempre com todos os registros da tabela ao passo que calcula as percentagens filtrando as datas com o 'between'. Para que fique correto você deve calcular a soma total com base nas mesmas condiçoes.

Comment: Eu experimentei também somar os registos, porém os resultados novamente não se mostravam corretos! Eu achei que podia fazer assim `Select count (*) as total from questionario` desde que tivesse o `where data between...`, da forma como eu pensei, ele iria contar todos os resultados entre essa data